# Laravel query by parent's parent

Tags: php, laravel

I have a few `belongsTo` relations in an app, with the 'lowest' child being an `Element`. The models have the following functions:

```
// Element
public function field(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Field');
} 
// Field
public function section(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Section');
} 
// Section
public function form(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Form');
}
```

How can I say something along the lines of:

```
$elements = Element::where('field.section.form.id', '=', 1);
```

And return all the elements that belong to the form with an ID of 1. Eager loading has served me well but I'm confused if there is a way of doing this.

Comment: Are you on Laravel 5 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereHas` (also with nested relationships since the latest 4.2 release. make sure to update to 4.2.17 if you haven't already)

```
$elements = Element::whereHas('field.section.form', function($q){
   $q->where('id', 1);
})->get();
```